# Efficient way to get key from value when map contain vector of string as value

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

How to get key using value which is vector of string and vice versa. Below is my code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> Mymap;
Mymap["unique1"] = {"hello", "world"};
Mymap["unique2"] = {"goodbye", "goodmorning", "world"};
Mymap["unique3"] = {"sun", "mon", "tue"};

for(auto && pair : Mymap) {
        for(auto && value : pair.second) {
                std::cout << pair.first<<" " << value<<"\n";
                if(value == "goodmorning") // how get key i.e unique2 ?
        }}
}
```

case 1: When value is input. key is output.

```
Input  : goodmorning
output : unique2
```

case 2: When key is input value is output.

```
Input : unique3
output: sun ,mon ,tue
```

Note : No boost library available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For case 1, a combination of `find_if` and `any_of` will do the job.

For case 2, you can simply use the `find` method of `unordered_map`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unordered_map<string, vector<string>> Mymap;
    Mymap["unique1"] = { "hello", "world" };
    Mymap["unique2"] = { "goodbye", "goodmorning", "world" };
    Mymap["unique3"] = { "sun", "mon", "tue" };

    // Case 1

    string test_value = "goodmorning";
    auto iter1 = find_if(Mymap.begin(), Mymap.end(),
        [&test_value](const decltype(*Mymap.begin()) &pair)
        {
            return any_of(pair.second.begin(), pair.second.end(), [&test_value](const string& str) { return str == test_value; });
        });

    if (iter1 != Mymap.end())
    {
        cout << "Key: " << iter1->first << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No key found for " << test_value;
    }

    // Case 2

    test_value = "unique3";
    auto iter2 = Mymap.find(test_value);
    if (iter2 != Mymap.end())
    {
        int first = true;
        for (auto v : iter2->second)
        {
            cout << (first ? "" : ", ") << v;
            first = false;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No value found for key " << test_value << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This what i am looking for but can you please help to compile on c++11 not 14

Comment: I need to compile on c++11 . Getting error as 
error: use of 'auto' in lambda parameter declaration only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14

Comment: @ava you can replace the `const auto &` with `unordered_map<string, vector<string>>::const_reference`

Comment: Why `Mymap[pair.first]` and not `pair.second`?

Comment: @Caleth when i place     unordered_map<string, vector<string>> Mymap;
in class as public data member its through compile time error

Comment: class a{

public:
    int mymain();
    unordered_map<string, vector<string>> Mymap;

};

int main()
{

a obj;
obj.mymain();
}

Comment: capture of non-variable ‘a::Mymap’ 
         [&test_value, &Mymap](unordered_map<string, vector<string>>::const_reference pair)
                        ^
stack_map.cc:13:43: note: ‘std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > a::Mymap’ declared here
     unordered_map<string, vector<string>> Mymap;
                                           ^
stack_map.cc: In lambda function:
stack_map.cc:36:27: error: ‘this’ was not captured for this lambda function
             return any_of(Mymap[pair.first].begin(), Mymap[pair.first].end(),

Comment: @ava You can't capture *members* of an object in a lambda, only the whole object. In this case you don't even need that capture. My second suggestion fixes that, replace `Mymap[pair.first]` with `pair.second` and remove the `&Mymap` from the lambda captures

Comment: @Caleth: You're right. I missed that. Thanks. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

The key is stored in `pair.first`. Just use that if your use-case is in loop iteration as you illustrated.

If you mean in any use, without iteration, that is, given a value obtain the associated key, there is not a direct way to do that. You could build inverse maps for each value to key but that would not be really efficient considering also the fact that you would also need unique values.

Answer (score 0):

Create another map going the other way for every vector entry?

If the array entries are not unique, then you would need to do the same map-to-vector, or use multimap.

Also consider using hash map (unordered_map), and stringview as ways to reduce the memory usage of the second map?

But the best answer would be the boost 2-way map, sorry. You could wrap the two maps in your own class that exposes the functionality of a 2-way map.